# TwentyThirteen - Footer overlapping content

Tags: content, footer

So, I'm designing a theme for a friend of mine, but there is a problem with the footer.

Assuming the very bottom of the browser window is 1000px, it seems that the page content ends at 1000px, and the footer sits between 900px - 1000px.

Thusly, the last 100px of content are cut off, and unreadable.

How can I move the bottom of the content to end at 900px, leaving room for the footer?

See here: http://level42.ca/village/contact-me/

Note the submit comment button is cut off.

---

I'm no expert by any means, and I hope what I've said makes sense.

Comment: My question was in regards to modifying the default twentythirteen theme from wordpress. I figured it would be easier to answer if the question was way more generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because your footer is fixed  which removes it from the normal page flow. You can add 50px padding-bottom to your #main div (or `.site-main` on line 790 of your style.css).

Overall this though isn't really a WordPress questions and more of a HTML / CSS Questions. Please visit [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: This actually works, and well. Thank you for this!

I wasn't sure whether or not this was a Wordpress issue, because it's related to the WP theme. But thank you :)

Comment: No problem! If it worked make sure to mark it answered (check mark on the left).

Comment: I had to wait 15 minutes before I could check it. I don't see why StackExchange can't understand that a question can be answered in less then 15 minutes. Thanks again.